# Symfony 4.2 can't Logout

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.2

I would like to implement the logout action on my `Symfony` project.

At the moment, when I make the logout action, I receive the exception

```
controller can be blank: it will never be executed!.
```

I've digged into internet and Symfony docs, normally this endpoint controller is never reached.

In my context,i can't logout and i don't know why this ***logout*** function is executed.

this is my configuration
**SecurityController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function logout()
{
    // controller can be blank: it will never be executed!
    throw new \Exception('controller can be blank: it will never be executed!');
}
```

**security.yaml**

```
firewalls:
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

main:
    anonymous: ~
    pattern:  /login
    provider: app_user_provider
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
    logout:
        path: app_logout
        # where to redirect after logout
        target: app_login
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You placed the logout listener in the "main" firewall, but the logout url is not covered by the pattern. So the request of "/logout" will not run thru it. You might place the logout listener into that firewall which covers the logout url **or** modify the "main" firewall's pattern to include the logout url. The latter looks like this:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
firewalls:
  main:
    # ...
    pattern: ^/(login|logout)$
    # ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out).

> To enable logging out, activate the logout config parameter under your firewall.

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
firewalls:
  main:
    # ...

    logout:
      path:   app_logout
      # where to redirect after logout
      # target: app_any_route
```

> Next, you'll need to create a route for this URL (**but not a controller**).

```
# config/routes.yaml
app_logout:
  path: /logout
  methods: GET
```

Comment: Love being downvoted while this works and I use this in all my apps.

Comment: This did not work for me.